# What dependencies to use for APACHE ODF TOOLKIT (INCUBATING)

Tags: java, dependencies, odf

I am trying to load a .ods file with the code:

```
import org.odftoolkit.simple.SpreadsheetDocument;
SpreadsheetDocument data = SpreadsheetDocument.loadDocument(f);
```

I've added the import statement to show which package I am using.

However I keep getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. I've tried adding many different libraries. At the moment I have these libraries in my eclipse build path: [libraries in my eclipse build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUwhl.png)

And am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/RDFNode
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.initialize(OdfFileDom.java:215)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.manifest.OdfManifestDom.initialize(OdfManifestDom.java:74)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.<init>(OdfFileDom.java:132)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.manifest.OdfManifestDom.<init>(OdfManifestDom.java:63)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfFileDom.newFileDom(OdfFileDom.java:189)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.parseManifest(OdfPackage.java:1187)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.readZip(OdfPackage.java:454)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.initializeZip(OdfPackage.java:425)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.<init>(OdfPackage.java:256)
    at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.loadPackage(OdfPackage.java:318)
    at org.odftoolkit.simple.Document.loadDocument(Document.java:319)
    at org.odftoolkit.simple.SpreadsheetDocument.loadDocument(SpreadsheetDocument.java:203)
    at FirstLoadComponent.main(FirstLoadComponent.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Any suggestion on how to get my code running or any alternative my to do simple read and writes to .ods files would be greatly appeciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `commons-validator-1.5.0.jar`, `jena-core-2.11.2.jar`, `jena-iri-1.0.2.jar` at least.

The full dependencies jars could be got via `maven` command `mvn dependency:tree`.

```
org.apache.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:jar:0.8.11-incubating
+- org.apache.odftoolkit:taglets:jar:0.8.11-incubating:compile
|  \- com.sun:tools:jar:1.7.0:system
+- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
+- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
+- org.apache.jena:jena-core:jar:2.11.2:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
|  +- org.apache.jena:jena-iri:jar:1.0.2:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.6:compile
|  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
+- net.rootdev:java-rdfa:jar:0.4.2:compile
\- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.5.0:compile
   +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
   +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
   +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
   \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
```

If you don't want to get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in future,
you should also add these jars. They can be found in **odfvalidator-1.1.8-incubating.war** of **odftoolkit-0.6.2-incubating-bin.zip**.